# How to fix Run-time error 1004 in very simple code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some of the most simple codes in the universe, but I don't understand why excel throws some errors to me/

I have tried few functions and etc, but still have this error.

In sheet2 in column A, I have values

```
Ra
S
S
```

---

```
Public Sub Data()
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngcells As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim checkvalue As Long
checkvalue = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



Set rngcells = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

Why set rngcells doesn't work?

Also! Can you please help to understand the following:

`checkvalue = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xldown).Row`, I receive some crazy number, whereas I am supposed to jump to last filled cell and there are only 3 filled cells? Why Using `xlUp` giving me the correct value for the last filled row?

Comment: The reason why you are having problems with `checkvalue = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xldown).Row` is because you are returning the `.Rows.Count` in column A and then using `.End(xlDown)`, which undoubtedly will take you to the bottom of your sheet. The code in your code block, using `.End(xlUp)` should return accurately. Using `.End(xlDown)` is like selecting the last cell in Col A and pressing Ctrl Down on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining the Sheet Name for second Call of `Range` in your Set statement

**Try:**

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rngcells = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))

End With
```

---

**This will give you the Lastrow starting from `A1` and going down.**

```
checkvalue = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Your line `checkvalue = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` should also give you the correct Lastrow if you have only 3 filled cells in Column A. Maybe a Look at the spreadsheet would make it clear. Post a Screenshot of the Data.

Comment: Mikku, Thank you a lot! And for editing the question as well.

Comment: So in order for it to work my way, I should have added Set rngcells = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown)) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. So if you use your previous statement, you should be on `Sheet2` for it to work. If any other sheet is activated, it will not work.